Using a msg file as a dictionary in python
I have this python script that analyzes rosbags. It works well for the most part.
However, there are certain messages in the rosbags that rely on a key-value pair defined in a message file. The file is defined as such:
uint8 type

uint8 STRING_A = 0
uint8 STRING_B = 1
...

I can import this in my python script and try to do something like:
import file.msg

file.STRING_A

But the issue here is, I get the integer value, and not the string value, in the rosbag analysis.
I'm thinking of making a function that takes the integer value, and then having a match case statement that tries to find the variable name that matches the int value. Something like:
def value_matcher(int_value):
    match int_value:
        case file.STRING_A:
            return "file.STRING_A"
        case file.STRING_B:
            return "file.STRING_B"
    

However, that could be cumbersome because of how many the values are. It's also inflexible if new messages get defined.
Is there a smarter way to go about this?
